Phase-shift of phase shift full bridge converter
For PSFB, I provided the waveforms of QA, QB, QC and QD mosfets and corresponding waveform formed on the transformer (Vsw) in the picture below.
When QA and QD conducts at the same the, the power is delivered to the secondary but QA-QD are not in phase. Likewise, situation is same for the QB-QC pairs.
As far as I know, this phase shift is the main parameter that controls duty, output power etc.
UCC28950 from Texas is used for this application.
The document link is https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf
I didn't understand how this phase shift between QA-QD or between QB-QC is determined/set on the controller?
Does controller set this phase shift automatically according to the duty cycle, input/output voltages etc.?
Additionally, we can only set the delay time between QA-QB and QC-QD to avoid shoot-through current and to improve the ZVS.

Source: https://digibuo.uniovi.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/10651/52653/TFM_AsselZhaksylyk.pdf?sequence=6

Mhan, if the question is answered, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.


Does controller set this phase shift automatically according to the
duty cycle, input/output voltages etc.?

Yes, and the controller will do something like this: -

We cannot be absolutely sure how they enact it because they don't tell us but, whenever I design a full-bridge LLC converter and need to simulate it I drag the above circuit out (my design). Here are some waveforms when Vin is linearly rising (seen at bottom of image): -

Vin is equivalent to the COMP pin on the UCC28950 (this pin can be overdriven with a strong input if it's anything like its earlier counterparts from Unitrode now part of TI).
P1 and P2 waveforms are the traditional bipolar duty cycle waveforms that get converted to the four MOSFET gate drive "phase shifted" waveforms using the D type flip-flops and the anti-shoot-through logic on the right hand side: -


You said in another comment that your question is about phase shift, not duty cycle. That is incorrect. Here phase shift and duty cycle are the same thing.
Trace out the QA, QB, QC and QD waveforms. Where do they overlap? Notice that there are times where both top FETs or both bottom FETs are on. Now look at the Vsw waveform. We see that Vsw has a positive hump where QA and QD are on and a negative hump where QB and QC are on. We can split the Vsw waveform into sections, we have the power strokes (positive and negative) and the recirculating time (both tops on or both bottoms on). The power stroke is where energy is delivered to the secondary. During recirculation, energy stored in the shim and/or transformer leakage flows around the primary (this is the same current that allows ZVS though).
In a PSFB, one leg "stays still" while the other shifts, but the individual legs are always at 50% duty cycle. We can imagine maximum duty cycle as the largest possible power strokes, and minimum duty cycle as the smallest power strokes AKA longest recirculating times. Therefore, in a PSFB you can think of Duty Cycle as the ratio between power stroke and recirculating time which is directly related to the phase shift between the legs.
This is akin to a simple Buck converter, longer on time for the top switch transfers more energy to the load/output cap. I believe it is easier to conceptualize these things when you start thinking about them as a transfer of energy.
If you're instead asking HOW the phase shift is done, then that is highly dependant on the IC/controller. Check out this paper by Cypress (now aquired by Infineon) titled AN76439 which covers one implementation. They use logic gates and a few flip-flops to do the actual signal generation.

Thank you for your comments, I was asking from the controller point of view, like how the controller sets it ? or we do something on the controller to determine it ? @Stiddily

Ah ok, in that case I would recommend looking into Error Amplifiers, and closed loop SMPS in general. The 3-input op-amp that winny was referencing is the Error Amplifier for the UCC28950. You can also have a discrete EA outisde of the chip and pump its output directly into the COMP pin. Basically, if the output voltage is too low, the EA starts to increase duty cycle by increasing its output voltage.  If the output voltage is too high, the Error Amp reduces its output voltage, reducing duty cycle. The rate at which the duty cycle increase and decreases is set by EA's feedback components

Unless softstart, OCP, light load skip mode or any other protection is in effect, your phase shift and thus duty cycle is set by the COMP value as seen in the datasheet.

0.8 V = 0 % duty cycle.
2.8 V = 100 % - deadband setting.


Image source: TI UCC28950 datasheet (https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/ucc28950)

My question is about phase shift, not duty cycle @winny

@Mhan You asked "Does controller set this phase shift automatically according to the duty cycle, input/output voltages etc.?" Your phase shift IS your output duty cycle in a PSFB.
